Android/iOSで「再インストールしても同じユーザーである事を識別する」 事は悪い事ではありませんか？
技術というより、考え方の質問になります。
自分の認識が古い、間違っているのであればアップデートしたいと考えています。
android/iOSのアプリで初回インストール時にだけ特典を付与します。
そのアプリにはアカウントのログインなどはありません。
再インストールして何度も特典が付与されるのは困ります。
iOSではidentifierForVendor、AndroidではSettings.Secure.ANDROID_ID の値をサーバーに送って初回インストールかを判断しようと思っているのですが、これはスマホアプリの文化的に許容されますでしょうか？
自分が不安になっているのは、iOSでUDIDやwifiのmacアドレス等、デバイスユニークなIDの取得が大昔は出来たけど広告のトラッキングに使われまくったから禁止されてリジェクト対象になったので
上記のようにユーザーを裏でこっそり識別する行為は今はもう完全に出来ないと思っていました。
ですが、上記の各種IDを見ると今でも普通に出来るし、現時点で"問題視されて次のバージョンから塞がれる"ような気配もありません。
これは、
「UDIDやmacアドレスは同じデバイスなら別のアプリでも同じ値を取得してユーザーの紐づけ出来るのがマズかった。
identifierForVendorやSettings.Secure.ANDROID_IDは同じ(ベンダーの)アプリ内でしか紐づけ出来ないから特に問題にならない」という事でしょうか？

短い答え : Yes
「別のアプリ」には「異なるベンダのアプリ」が含まれていて、よって UDID/mac が取得できると「異ベンダが連絡しあうとより一層細かいユーザーの特定ができてしまう」ので絶対マズイのです。
中古スマホを買った「甲」、それを売ったショップ「乙」、乙にスマホを売った「丙」がいるとして、１アプリのベンダがこの３者をトラックできるというのもまずいでしょ。
identifierForVendor や Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID は上記のような状況でトラックできないように仕様策定されているので問題ないです。

ユーザーを裏でこっそり識別する行為は

ベンダーから見てユーザーの識別が一切できないとなると課金系ゲームって成り立たないわけです。なので MNP / 機種変更しても「このベンダーのこのゲームから見て同一ユーザーである」ことの識別はできなければエコシステムが成り立ちません。「異なるベンダーのアプリから見て」「同一ベンダーの別アプリから見て」同一ユーザーであると判断できるのはマズイ。なので「明示的に識別」はできて当たり前です。「こっそり」はダメでしょ。

identifierForVendor の解説ページの１つ によると

ユーザーがあるベンダーのアプリを全てアンインストールし、その後それらを再インストールした場合、identifierForVendor はリセットされるということです。

ということなので、これがあなたのところの要望に一致するか否かは事前に判断が必要っス。
